# sending email with all my name list array

Tags: php

I have an array passed to the following script with a submit form, then send a email using those data.

**PHP**

```
$boxName = $_POST['name'];    
$m = new PHPMailer();

foreach ($boxName as $named)
{
    $m->Body = "Name:" .$named. "<br>";
};
```

**The array**

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => Chris [1] => Yum [2] => Oppa [3] => mudo)
```

Bbut i only get the last name show on my email, why? I already use foreach to open all. If i use `print_r` it will show all my name list. The sending part have no problem, i just don't know how to get all my name list into message.

How do i make my `$m->body` show all my name list?

If i use the following code, i can see all my name list

```
foreach ($boxNumber as $Name) { 
    print $Name."<br>";
}
```

I want to show the list like the following example:

```
1.Chris
2.Yum
3.Oppa
4.mudo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can only see the last name is because you are overwriting the Body variable each time you execute the loop. Please see code below.

```
  $boxName = $_POST['name'];

    $m = new PHPMailer();
    $m->Body = '<ol>';
    foreach ($boxName as $named)
        $m->Body .= "<li>" . $named . "</li>";
    $m->Body .= "</ol>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always overwriting the last name, what you need is to actually **append** the string (using the period):

```
$m->Body .= "Name:" .$named. "<br>";
// this is the short form for:
$m->Body = $m->Body . "Name:" .$named. "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code

```
$boxName = $_POST['name'];    
$m = new PHPMailer();

if(empty($m->body)) $m->Body = ''

$i = 1;
foreach ($boxName as $named)
{
    $m->Body .= $i.'.'.$named. "<br>";

    $i += 1;
};
```